# Variable name in a loop using an integer

Tags: swift, syntax

I want to change the text of a lot of labels. All my labels are named `LabelName1`, `LabelName2`, `LabelName3`.

How can I edit my labels with one loop like this:

```
for i in 1..10 {
    LabelName(i).Text = String(some text, the some for each label)
}
```

Comment: Variable names don't exist after compilation. They're stand-ins for memory addresses that programming languages use for programmer convenience.

Answer (score 4):

You should store all of your `UILabels` in an array and change the text for all of them like this:

```
for label in labelArray {
    label.text = String(some text, the some for each label)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to @toddg fine answer, you could assign a specific tag to the labels and loop through the subviews:

```
// loop through subviews and update all UILabels with a tag property of 4
for view in self.subviews as [UIView] {
    if let label = view as? UILabel {
        if label.tag == 4 {
            label.text = String(some text, the some for each label)
        }
    }
}
```

The advantages to this is no arrays are needed, and you can be as specific or generic as desired.